# Assign Attribute to another Dto

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, class-validator

I'm working on a nestjs project and I'm wondering if I can assign a value Attribute to another Dto, to explain more.

the case is I want to assign idData to id in IsUniqueValidator.

I tried this code but it returns undefined :

```
export class UpdateCompanyDto {

public idData  ;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Validate(IsUniqueValidator, 
    [ { table: "company", column: "name",isNumber : false,id: this.idData ,columnid : "id"   }] )
  companyname: string;
```

Result :

```
    {
  table: 'company',
  column: 'name',
  isNumber: false,
  id: undefined,
  columnid: 'id'
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assign it, you can find it in the handler

```js
validate(value: any, validationArguments?: ValidationArguments) {
  console.log(validationArguments.object.idData);
}
```

```js
export interface ValidationArguments {
    value: any;
    constraints: any[];
    targetName: string;
    object: Object; // <- that's what you need
    property: string;
}
```